# Compile multiple source files in an Autoconf test

Tags: autotools, autoconf, static-order-fiasco

I'm working on a test for GCC `init_priority` and MSC `init_seg`. I want to craft a test to compile and link two source files in a specific order.

I'm having trouble finding information on compiling and linking two source files using `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` or `AC_LINK_IFELSE`. The Autoconf docs don't appear to discuss the use case. Searching for terms like *"Autoconf test with two source files"* are returning irrelevant results. I think I might be missing good search terms.

Is it possible to use two source files during an Autoconf test? If so, then how do I do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to test linking the to compiled objects *to each other*?  I don't think Autoconf has built-in support for that, and I'm having trouble seeing how it would be useful.  Can you explain why you want to do it?

Comment: @John - I need to finish implementing the two tests under the [Init Priorities](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools/blob/master/configure.ac#L381) heading.

Comment: Is there genuine reason for concern that `init_priority` or `init_seg` would work as advertised within the scope of a single translation unit, but not have the desired effect across translation unit boundaries?  Indeed, is there reason for concern that one of these will fail to work across translation boundaries with a compiler that accepts them at all?

Comment: And do you have a mitigation for the event that the test fails (in which case you could just apply that unconditionally), or do you intend to just make configuration fail if the test fails?

Comment: @John - If the tests for Init Priorities fail then we have to fallback to to a different pattern. The fallback patterns have their own shortcomings. The reason we want a test link and run is, OS X compilers claim support of init priorities but the linker ignores the information. Other platforms may do the same. So we could suffer a Type II failure (failing to reject a bad) which could lead to using the wrong pattern for the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` and `AC_LINK_IFELSE` do not serve the purpose you describe, and they are not intended to do.  Each takes *one* source, performs its test, and cleans up after itself.  I didn't even find a macro for what you want at [the Autoconf archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/), which provides a number of sometimes-useful macros that don't ship with Autoconf itself.  What you're proposing to do is far out of the ordinary, so if you want to proceed then I think you'll need to roll your own.  Possibly it would help to consult the implementations of `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` and `AC_LINK_IFELSE`.

But do sit back and have a think first, because I don't think such a test would be meaningful anyway. C++ relative initialization order across translation units is completely unspecified without use of an extension such as `init_priority` or `init_seg`.  The language provides no justification for an assumption that it has anything to do with the order in which objects appear on a linker command line, nor even for an assumption that initializations arising from different TUs won't be intermixed.  Thus, even if a test of cross-TU initialization happens to pass, that does not convey any actionable information, because there's no basis for certainty that whatever characteristic you are trying to test is responsible for the success.

I considered suggesting just a test for in-TU initialization reordering via `init_priority`, which you could perform with `AC_RUN_IFELSE`.  That's not useful to you either, however, because you apparently need to support MSVC++, which does not provide a mechanism to modulate initialization order at that granularity.

Ultimately, then, I think the best you can do is to test whether `init_priority` or `init_seg` is accepted *at all* by the compiler (which you can do with `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`), and suppose that if so, it in fact does the job it is supposed to do.